# why do we need the (pid) controllers in ros_control?

Tags: ros, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example, I have a robot with a motor controlled by a embeded board and I want to use ros applications to control the robot. Usually, there is a pid , let's say, speed controller implemented in the embeded board(or in the driver of motor). The SBC send(write) speed control signals to the embeded board. So I believe all we need is a hardware interface to translate ros msgs to embeded's control signal. what is the point of controllers in ros_control? Can I only implement a hardware interface and how?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393342/why-do-we-need-the-(pid)-controllers-in-ros_control?/) by [zhixin](https://answers.ros.org/users/92194/zhixin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-12-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @zhixin, let's start with `ros_control` package:

> The ros_control packages are a rewrite
> of the pr2_mechanism packages to make
> controllers generic to all robots
> beyond just the PR2.
>
> The ros_control packages takes as
> input the joint state data from your
> robot's actuator's encoders and an
> input set point. It uses a generic
> control loop feedback mechanism,
> typically a PID controller, to control
> the output, typically effort, sent to
> your actuators. ros_control gets more
> complicated for physical mechanisms
> that do not have one-to-one mappings
> of joint positions, efforts, etc but
> these scenarios are accounted for
> using transmission

Source: http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control
One of the goals of ROS is not to re-invent the wheel so `ros_control` package allows for wide range of applications.
However it's not the only way to interact with Hardware, you could do that through ROS1 messages and services.
Refer to this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

And take a look at example of robot implementation, you can communicate with drivers or other interfaces.
https://docs.niryo.com/dev/ros/v3.2.0/en/source/stack_hardware/niryo_robot_hardware_interface.html#hardware-interface-node

Finally I suggest you look at what is also available with ROS2 control: http://control.ros.org/

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhixin](https://answers.ros.org/users/92194/zhixin/) on 2022-01-02**:
Thank you, Very informative anwser. So there are many ways to interact with the hardware. For the message and services as you mentioned, say I want controll a motor by sending the signal through a series port, I think the "actual send signal code" should be written in a node "control_signal_publisher", the messge is given to the topic not the actual SBC port. And I should assure the sended signal and the messge is the same. Is that right?

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-02**:
Take a look at this example using Arduino and rosserial: https://www.google.com/amp/s/atadiat.com/en/e-rosserial-arduino-introduction/

I think you can do something similar. Not sure what do you mean by assuring the sent signal and message are the same, can you explain further pls

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-02**:
If the answer responded the original question please accept by clicking on the check mark

**Comment by [zhixin](https://answers.ros.org/users/92194/zhixin/) on 2022-01-02**:
First thanks for the rosserial example, it solve my confusion. Then forget about "assuring the sent signal and message are the same". I just misundertand the communication between SBC and Arduino board: not realized that there is ros interface not only on SBC but also on Arduino. So rosseriel and ros_lib do the stuff I meant. User needn't to directly handle the seriel port(connect SBC and Arduino) stuff.